# reload or re render react child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i got trouble making a search function in react, not the function itself but how it redirecting. before i've tried using redirect and it doesn't load the parent component. no solution, then i changes the logic using Link to instead of redirect to. now the problem is the child component doesnt re-render and the only thing changes is the url.

Here is the complete code.

Child component:

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    products: [],
    count: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cari/' + params.userId)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ products: response.data.data, count: response.data.jumlah });
      })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.forceUpdate();
    this.setState({ diCari: this.state.diCari });
  }

  render() {
    var jumlah = <div className="judul cari">Menampilkan {this.state.count} Produk</div>;
    var { products } = this.state;
    var hasil = products.map(products => {
      <div className="kotakproduk produkcari" />
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="gambarproduk">
          <img src="https://www.mobiledokan.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Xiaomi-Mi-9-Pro-Dream-White.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div className="nama">
          {products.merk} {products.tipe}
        </div>
        <div className="harga">
          <NumberFormat value={products.harga} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'Rp. '} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Parent component

```
class Master extends Component {
  state = {
    cari: '',
    diCari: false
  };

  handleChange1 = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      cari: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <Link to="/home">
            <div className="logo">
              <img src="/img/tokopon2.png" />
            </div>
          </Link>
          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onChange={this.handleChange1} />
          <Link to={"/search/" + this.state.cari}><button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button></Link>
          <div className="login-button">
            <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            <div className="keranjang-mobile">
              <a href="#">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="keranjang">
              <a href="#" className="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Keranjang Belanja
                 </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

i already tried history.push still no changes

Comment: Perhaps you could fix the code's indentation a bit, it's pretty difficult to read through.

Comment: @YannickK Done, please review if you can.

Comment: I'm not gonna read through all that, but I have a quick suggestion that might help you: changing the `key` of a react component causes it to re-render from scratch.

Comment: it's difficult to understand your query, your code looking is fine, try to use react-redux or react conext api

Comment: @TKoL where should i put the key?

Comment: Wherever the component is that you want to re-render. `<MyComponent key={this.state.myComponentKey} />`. This will re-render MyComponent from scratch - the constructor will run account, ComponentDidMount will run again. Then if you want your component to re-render, all you have to do is change the state of `myComponentKey` in the parent component.

Comment: what do you mean by mycomponent ? is that the .js file or the div at render? i'm sorry, i'm really a newbie here